# Retrieve huge strings from database and concatenate them

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have to collect some huge strings (xml parts) from database, concatenate them to one big xml and send it with asp.net mvc to client.

The problem is, the created xml is to big to keep in memory (OutOfMemoryException is thrown), so i am looking for a way to stream it to client and concatenate it on demand.

I tried to use my own FileResult as return and writing direct to the response stream

```
protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
{
    response.Write("<Accounts>");
    ...
    //Get the rows one by one and write them to the response stream here
    ...
    response.Write("</Accounts>");    
}
```

But that will also end in an OutOfMemoryException.

So what can I use?

Comment: Are you using any ORM to get your data or are you using the standard SqlClient?

Comment: I am using linq to sql, and i am disposing the datacontext everytime i have read 10 lines from database. So this should not be the problem.

Comment: The reason I ask this, is that with the standard SqlClient on .NET 4.5 you can make use of async/await, as the SqlClient also allows Async Task based methods to be utilised. Doing so, will allow you to spread the workload across multiple processors and memory if your system supports this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `response.BufferOutput = false;` at the beginning of `WriteFile`.

And call `Flush` every some writes.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. Sometimes one line of code changes your hole world :-)

Comment: Happy to hear that it was of help! :)